# Vue.js: show profile image in laravel public folder

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, image, vue.js

I am creating commenting system.
And I integrated vue.js in my laravel project.

> In my comment area, I want to show user profile image in my laravel
>   public folder.

But I have no idea how to show image.

What I want to achieve is,

> if user has a profile image, I want to show it in comment area. But if
>   user doesn't have a profile image, I want to show an avatar.

I used vue avatar component so I think I want to use it.

My profile images are stored in **public/uploads/profile.**

**comment.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="reply-comment" >
            <div class="user-comment">
            <div class="user">
                <!---<img src="{{ $comment->user->img }}" class="image-preview__image">--->
                <avatar :username="comment.user.name" :size="45"></avatar>
            </div>
            <div class="user-name">
                <span class="comment-name"><a :href=" '/user/' + 'profile' +'/'+ comment.user.id + '/'  ">{{ comment.user.name }}</a></span>
                <p>{{ comment.body }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reply">
        <button @click="addingReply = !addingReply" class="reply-button" :class="{ 'red' : !addingReply, 'black' : addingReply }">
            {{ addingReply ? 'Cancel' : 'Add Reply'}}
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="user-reply-area" v-if="addingReply">
        <div class="reply-comment">
            <input v-model='body' type="text">
        </div>
            <button @click="addReply" class="comment-button"><span>Add Reply</span></button>
    </div>
     <replies ref='replies' :comment="comment"></replies>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Avatar from 'vue-avatar'
import Replies from './replies.vue'
export default {
    components: {
        Avatar,
        Replies
    },
    data() {
        return {
            body: '',
            addingReply: false
        }
    },
    props: {
        comment: {
            required: true,
            default: () => ({})
        },
        post: {
            required: true,
            default: () => ({})
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addReply() {
            if(! this.body) return
            axios.post(`/comments/${this.post.id}`, {
                comment_id: this.comment.id,
                body: this.body
            }).then(({data})=> {
                this.body = ''
                this.addingReply = false
                this.$refs.replies.addReply(data)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        });
     }
    }
}
</script>
```

**profile.php**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

**user.php**

```
public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }

 public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
```

**comment.php**

```
protected $with = ['user'];

protected $appends = ['repliesCount'];
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('results/{post}/comments', 'CommentController@index');
```

Comment: how do you call the image path? Are you saving the image name in `database` or the path?

Comment: @GayanS.Muthukumarana Sorry, what do you mean ? Thank you for help.

Comment: I've edited my comment

Comment: @GayanS.Muthukumarana Thanks,  I have saved file name in mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

If your database column name for the image file is **`img`** then
you can do it like below:

```
<div class="user" v-if="comment.user.img">
    <img :src="'uploads/profile/'+comment.user.img">
</div>
<div class="user" else>
    <img :src="default_image_path_here">
</div>
```

If you are using multiple images for a user you need to add a loop as follow:

```
<div class="user" v-if="comment.user.img.length > 0">
    <span v-for="(item, index) in comment.user.img">
         <img :src="'uploads/profile/'+item.your_image_name_column">
    </span>
</div>
<div class="user" else>
    <img :src="default_image_path_here">
</div>
```

Comment: I hope that your result of the img name is output when calls `comment.user.img`.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work... I tried this  <div class="user" v-if="comment.user.img">
                    <img :src="'uploads/profile/'+comment.user.img">
                </div>
                <div class="user" else>
                    <avatar :username="comment.user.name" :size="45"></avatar>
                </div>

Comment: I have many user image, so Not only one image, I want to retrieve multiple images of users.

Comment: Then you need to add a loop in it

Comment: Thank you, could you please show me loop code ? Thank you so much.

Comment: I got errors TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined and "TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null"

Comment: That's because I just put dummy here. because I don't know exactly what will be the output and are those keywords I used correct or not. You may use the correct keywords that you used to retrieve the results. Try `console.log` and put correct column names and etc.

Comment: I put this <div class="user" v-if="comment.user.image.length > 0">
                    <span v-for="(item, index) in comment.user.image">
                        <img :src="'uploads/profile/'+ item.image">
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="user" v-else>
                    <avatar :username="comment.user.name" :size="45"></avatar>
                </div> because my column name is image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201000/discussion-between-gayan-s-muthukumarana-and-yohei-umezu).